# Determining when all UIPanGestureRecognizer views have completed their panning

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a set of UIImageViews that are placed on the screen. Each of these image views have a label on them that I have to compare whether it is abc order or not. Each image view has a UIPanGesture attached to it. It starts out with 3, and if the user gets them in the right order, it will jump to 5. The issue is holding the comparison until all (3, 5, etc) image views are in their places. This has been driving me crazy because I cannot figure it out.

I need help figuring out how to determine how many image views have been moved, and when all of them are done.

Such as: 3 image views.

When imageView1 and imageView2 are done with their panning, they won't do anything until imageView3 has completed it's panning. So far, my code only works when a single imageView is done panning. Here is the code below.

self.carsLevel is where the 3, 5, and etc come from.

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
if ([pan state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [pan state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:[pan.view superview]];

    [pan.view setCenter:CGPointMake([pan.view center].x + translation.x, [pan.view center].y + translation.y)];
    [pan setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[pan.view superview]];
}
else {

    NSString *s1 = self.label1.text;
    NSString *s2 = self.label2.text;
    NSString *s3 = self.label3.text;
    NSString *s4 = self.label4.text;
    NSString *s5 = self.label5.text;
    NSString *s6 = self.label6.text;
    NSString *s7 = self.label7.text;

    for (int i = 0; i <= self.carsLevel; i++) {
        if (pan.view.tag == i) {
            NSLog(@"pan tag = %lu", (unsigned long)pan.view.tag);
            if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
                if (self.carsLevel == 3) {
                    [self compare:s1 to:s2];
                    [self compare:s2 to:s3];
                }
                else if(self.carsLevel == 5) {

                }
                else if(self.carsLevel == 7) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something along this:

```
else {
NSInteger carLevels = self.carsLevel;

if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
     ++_countSoFar;   // _countSoFar is an iVar
}
if (_countSoFar == carLevel)
{
//  do what you need to be done
     _countSoFar = 0;  //reset count
}
```